# Why blueprint framework defines margin-bottom on headers and text sizes?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

Why Blueprint CSS framework defines quite big margin-bottom style property on headers (h1,h2,...) and on `small` and `large` classes? It looks quite weird - for example, on `small` text it gives a hole three times bigger under the text. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the framework, or better: a jsFiddle demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's merely a choice that the designer(s) made. You can see from the [test page](http://blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/elements.html) that it produces a fairly clean layout with plenty of white space, enough to make each block of text easily readable.

If you are getting different results, make sure the undesirable behavior isn't caused by one of your own CSS files. You are free to edit any of the stylesheets in *any* CSS framework or replace them with your own. Personally, I encourage it.

For whatever it's worth, I personally dislike Blueprint's typography stylesheet and agree that it's awkward. I've used Blueprint as a base many times and one of the first things I always end up adjusting is the heading elements.

So the reason and answer to your question: It was a stylistic choice. Feel free to make your own.